# Does the EJB container removes all the EJB objects in call hierarchy if last EJBBean method throws SystemException?

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6

Following is some sudo code:

```
//controller method
public String method1()
{
    EJBBean1 bean1;
    bean1.method1();
}

//EJBBean1 class
public void method1()
{
    EJBBean2 bean2;
    bean2.method2();
}

//EJBBean2 class
public void method2()
{
    EJBBean3 bean3;
    bean3.method3();
}

//EJBBean3 class
public void method3()
{
    throw NullPointerException();
}
```

The EJB objects are injected through dependency injection.

**Does the EJB container removes all the EJB objects (EJBBean1, 2 & 3) if method3 of EJBBean3 throws SystemException?**

Comment: what you mean by remove ? is it stateless / statefull ?

Comment: Remove means whether the ejb instance is discarded by the EJB container or not. All beans are statefull bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Normal Case**

Nested StateFullEJB  has special behavior , The contained EJB Holds the session.

In your case, EjbBean1 holds new dedicated EjbBean2 when EjbBean1 get destroyed EjbBean2 also would get destroy. Same case applies to EjbBean2 - EjbBean3 .

So it is EjbBean1 responsibility to call the remove in EjbBean2.remove in EjbBean1.remove method ( @Remove method).

[Samples](http://marcovaltas.com/2008/10/26/stateful-session-beans-dependence-injection-and-remove-annotation.html)

**And for the Exception case....**

```
    When ever a System Exception thrown by a bean method, EJB Container invalidates 
the EJB object and destroys the bean instance.The bean instance directly moved into
 DOES not exists state and any @PreDestroy methods are not invoked.

A System  exception is any unchecked Exception not annotated as an @Application Exception
```

Refer [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=q9FQmcgxXTgC&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=UnChecked%20Exception%20and%20StateFul%20EJb&source=bl&ots=aAgGEP8xNw&sig=cN42Hg0x_4jZ9z2XsllFEpV9hY4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5mB7U6L2EISVyATmoYKwBw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=UnChecked%20Exception%20and%20StateFul%20EJb&f=false)

Thus your EjbBean3 will be destroyed automatically by the Ejb Container and the exception propagates to Parent method EjbBean2 and EJbBean1  . Since none of the bean is catching the NullPointerException 
these instances would remove automatically by the container.

NOte** , Assumed NullPointerException is an System Exception ( i.e not annotated / configured )

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation. So this means all three ejb instances will be removed from the container. Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: It is not make sense to handle this scenario, since these are System Exception.If required for what ever reason,you can catch RuntimeException  and wrap it around Application Exception

Answer (score 0):

Only if they are not @Singleton beans.